# mysql select on two different tables depending on field-value

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select

I have the following problem and my brain burns out :)

I have two tables with personal data (one for customer 'table_a' and one for interesting peoples 'table_b'). 
In a third table 'table_inv' there are entries with invited_persons from both tables (a nd b).

The table_inv has a field 'invited_id' in which the id from table a or table b is stored. Another field 'type' has the value 'cust' or 'interest' to separate from which table (a or b) the entry comes.

Now i have to get the full data from table_a / table_b depending on the value from field 'type'...

I tried it whith case and if but with no result.

I'm searching for something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.created, a.userid, a.type, a.inviteid, b.name_first, b.name_last, b.zip, b.city
FROM ext_event_invites a
CASE a.type
    WHEN 'CUST' THEN
        LEFT JOIN accounts b ON a.inviteid = b.id;
    ELSE
        LEFT JOIN ext_contacts b ON a.inviteid = b.id;
END CASE
WHERE a.eventid = :eventid AND a.userid = '4711' 
ORDER BY b.name_last ASC, b.name_first ASC
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply join to both tables and then conditionally select the data from the relevant one. Another option is given below. I've assumed the alternative to `'CUST'` is `'CONT'` (for 'Contact'), so you'll need to tweak that if it's something else ...

```
SELECT
    a.id, a.created, a.userid, a.type, a.inviteid,
    b.name_first, b.name_last, b.zip, b.city
FROM
    ext_event_invites i
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
    SELECT
       'CUST' as type,
       a.name_first,
       a.name_last,
       a.zip,
       a.city
    FROM accounts a

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
       'CONT' as type,
       c.name_first,
       c.name_last,
       c.zip,
       c.city
    FROM ext_contacts c
    ) as b ON
       i.inviteid = b.id AND
       i.type = b.type
WHERE
    a.eventid = :eventid AND a.userid = '4711' 
ORDER BY
    b.name_last ASC,
    b.name_first ASC
```

Comment: @pengels. Do let me know if this has worked for you. If not, do let me know and I'll try to fix. If so, please mark the answer as "accepted" by way of a thank you.

Comment: Just spotted some typos with my aliases. These are now corrected. Do let me know how you get on with this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. This should work.

```
SELECT a.id, a.created, a.userid, a.type, a.inviteid, b.name_first, b.name_last, b.zip, b.city
FROM ext_event_invites a
IF a.type = 'CUST' THEN
    LEFT JOIN accounts b ON a.inviteid = b.id;
ELSE
    LEFT JOIN ext_contacts b ON a.inviteid = b.id;
WHERE a.eventid = :eventid AND a.userid = '4711' 
ORDER BY b.name_last ASC, b.name_first ASC
```

Comment: Did  you try this before positing it? It doesn't work